# How to override form validation methods in Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6

When we submit the form without filling in the required (`setRequired(true)`) field values, it errors out.
I want to override the method that displays these error messages.

P.S. I know how to customize these error messages by properties files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the error messages you have to use `FeedbackPanel` (or actually any class implementing `IFeedback`). By overriding `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel#newMessageDisplayComponent()` you can use a custom Component to render each feedback message.

Comment: I came across that method but the problem is, that method has a `FeedbackMessage` object as param, there does not seem to be any method in the that object to change the feedback message. Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: I need to edit the message in the newMessageDisplayComponent method

Comment: You can ignore the passed parameter and return a Label with totally different model object. I guess there is a better solution but I'll need more information for the whole case.

Comment: how exactly can I replace it with a Label and what better solutions are you talking about, if you can just point me in the right direct then I ll go find the solution.

Comment: Did solve it by creating a new FeedabckMessage object